# PHP: Apply a common filter with filter_var_array?

Tags: php, arrays, filter, sanitization

I've tried various combinations and permutations of `filter_var_array()` and have yet to find the answer to this:

Given a rather large associative array, I need to apply `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` with the `FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW` flag to ALL of the elements in the array.

So:

```
filter_var_array($my_big_array,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

applies the `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` filter but without the `FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW` flag.

And...

```
filter_var_array($my_big_array,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
```

Brings up an error.

Is it possible to easily apply a common filter using `filter_var_array()`?

Comment: I have an answer for you. See below. I'd appreciate the points if this is a good answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Good filter_var_array() syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172026/php-5-4-can-i-use-multiple-flags-with-a-filter-using-filter-var-array)

The second filter_var_array() argument needs to be a proper $definition as per the PHP manual.

Example:

Just make sure you *do not* put the flags inside their own array. Options can be in an array, but the flags need to be seen as one whole thing separated by pipes.

```
   $def = [
             'firstName' => ['filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                             'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR | FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH],
             'lastName'  => ['filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                             'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR | FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH]
          ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to combine them via binary operators, as in `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING & FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW`, but I haven't tested this yet.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work afterall. It seems to destroy the array and lose all its data.