# PHP 5.4: Can I use multiple flags with a filter using filter_var_array()?

Tags: php

[PHP Manual: filter_var_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php)

```
mixed filter_var_array ( array $data [, mixed $definition [, bool $add_empty = true ]] )
```

Can something like this for the *$definition* argument of a `filter_var_array()` call ever work? (array syntax >= PHP5.4)

```
   $def = [
         'firstName' => ['filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                         'flags'  => [FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR | FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH]],
         'lastName'  => ['filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                         'flags'  => [FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR | FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH]],
   ];
```

Is using only one flag at a time the only way to use flags when using `filter_input_array()`? For example: (written out the long way, although I could do this with a loop).

```
   $def1 = [
         'firstName' => ['filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                         'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR],
         'lastName'  => ['filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                         'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR]
   ];

   $def2 = [
         'firstName' => ['filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                         'flags'  => FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES],
         'lastName'  => ['filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                         'flags'  => FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES]
   ];

   $def3 = [
         'firstName' => ['filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                         'flags'  => FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW],
         'lastName'  => ['filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                         'flags'  => FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW]
   ];

   $def4 = [
         'firstName' => ['filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                         'flags'  => FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH],
         'lastName'  => ['filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                         'flags'  => FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH]
   ];
```

Comment: This probably works if the 'flags' are not inside their own array, as in the first code block in this question. Testing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just make sure you do not put the flags inside their own array. Options can be in an array, but the flags need to be seen as one whole thing separated by the bitwise OR operator (`|`).

```
   $def = [
      'firstName' => ['filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                       'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR | FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH],
      'lastName'  => ['filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                       'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR | FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH]
   ];
```

Comment: And what if you want to do FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL and FILTER_CALLBACK? Still need to do two of them?

Comment: That's right. In fact, I have a class that does FILTER_CALLBACK for sanitizing, then I run my fields through the whole thing again with FILTER_SANTIZE_EMAIL or whatever field specific filter applies.  Moreover, I have a second class that handles validation. This time, I let it run its field specific FILTER_VALIDATE_BLAH filter first, then I use FILTER_CALLBACK again to run my custom validation routines. In short, sanitize (custom, php filter stuff) then validate (php filter stuff, custom validators).

Comment: Those "pipes" are actually the bitwise OR operator. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php