# PHP are patterns still necessary or does filter_var take care of it all

Tags: php, regex, filter-var

As I was reading an article this morning I came across this

> Most people tend to think of data validation as an immensely tedious
>   process where one either:
>
> Compares the data they want to validate against every possible
>   combination they can think of. Tries to find a golden Regular
>   Expression that will match every possible combination. 
> A combination
>   of the two. 
> There are obvious problems with the above listed:
>
> It's absolutely time consuming. There is a very high chance of error.
>   Fortunately, beginning with version 5.2, PHP has included a great
>   function called filter_var that takes away the pain of data
>   validation.

Are patterns still neccessary or does `filter_var` just do it all.

Comment: Depends on what and how you want to validate your data.

Comment: Lets just say a simple form with some text inputs, an email, and a phone number.

Comment: The [manual](http://php.net/filter_var) may offer some insight into this for you.

Comment: For the email you can easily use `filter_var()` for the phone number you have to write your own validation, for the length and that it only contains number

Comment: Depends whether you allow phone number entry like `+44 1772 536421` or other variants... as most phone numbers have national variant formats, you probably need to define the permitted patterns yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by patterns you mean regular expressions, then the answer to your question is *yes*. Why? The built in filters may not sanitize or validate your data exactly how you want. The filters may be overly broad, or they may conform too rigidly to standards for your particular circumstance. The filters many not actually conform to standards at all.

For example, `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` and `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` might might allow strange email addresses that, while technically legal in the RFC sense, may be undesirable depending on your needs. It is up to you as the developer, the creator of your application, to decide what you really want to accept for an e-mail address.

The PHP filter creators understood that one size fits all is an impractical proposition. Therefore, you can supply your own sanitizing/validating filter with `FILTER_CALLBACK` and your own validating filter using `FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP`. Are we back at square one? Are we better off?

The real question is are you willing to *buy in and accept* the "filtering framework/methodology" established by the PHP filter system. Do I? I use their filter system as a first pass, then I use my own carefully crafted sanitizers and validators (yes, I use both `FILTER_CALLBACK` and `FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP` on top of the generic sanitizers/validators). This is especially true for me when processing HTML forms, as I no longer use $_POST and $_GET. I use `filter_input_array()` .

So, Mr. Smithyyy, don't reinvent the wheel, but do think for yourself. The key to using the PHP filter system is to create a system, and for some (like me) that means wrapping the filter functions in class. Using various class properties that might store predefined filters, one could imagine a system where various methods, using loops, filter all your data, leaving you with the final output of a good array, or a bad one (which you can take action on, based on your particular circumstance). But, as Mr. Wall of the Perl community notes, "There's more than one way to do it."

Comment: Look here for a way to pre-stage PHP filters. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172026/php-5-4-can-i-use-multiple-flags-with-a-filter-using-filter-var-array

Answer (score 1):

[Filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) are indeed very useful and if you can avoid a classical string approach or a regex, don't hesitate to use them.

Unfortunately, a predefined filter for each format is not possible!

This is why there is two special filters: `FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP` and `FILTER_CALLBACK` *(this last isn't really a validation filter but nothing forbids the callback function to return a boolean)* to build all missing validation filters. But when you need to use these two special filters the situation isn't really different than before PHP 5.2.

In my opinion, the main goal of `filter_vars` is to provide an as most as possible handy, but especially *unique* way for validation and filtering tasks. I think the performance aspect is totally secondary.

**about email and urls:**

`FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` and `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` are unable to validate all possible emails or urls, but you will experiment the same problem (with perhaps other limitations) with a regex approach or other home-made string validation.

URL and EMAIL validation suffer from the same diseases: several RFC exists (for different reasons: update, internationalization) that describes these formats which are complicated, not well know and unevenly spread and supported by apps.

In the same way, it's difficult to build a code or a pattern to validate them in a fast way. Patterns you can see for emails or URLs are with varying degrees a compromise between the most common and the most exotic formats.

Moreover, the volatility of an URL or an email makes that the only foolproof validation method is to verify that it really exists. So verifying the format is only a step of the validation process and must be relativized.