# Filter_var_array() in PHP

Tags: php, filter-var

Good day, this code is wrong:

```
filter_var_array(['<b> text</b>  \`/ =)', ' " \ " '], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
```

Why the flag `FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES` isn't working?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: _“Why the flag FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES isn't working?”_ – because you are passing it as the _third_ parameter to the function, which has a totally different meaning.

Comment: Thanks! It's very interesting!

Comment: But what I must to do?

Comment: TIIUNDER there aren't any error messages

Comment: @LittleByte Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172026/php-5-4-can-i-use-multiple-flags-with-a-filter-using-filter-var-array

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a comma, so your flag is given to filter_var_array as third argument.

try:

```
filter_var_array(['<b> text</b>  \`/ =)', ' " \ " '],
FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS ^ FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
```

instead